# Symfony2 Form : Preselected value is lost in editAction

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

It seems that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know where.
I have a Choicelist `motif` like the following :

```
//....
$builder->add('motif', 'choice', array(
    'label' => 'Motif',
    'choice_list' => $motifs, //array of entities
    'empty_value' => "Please select motif ..."
));
```

The `Motif` Entity:

```
class Motif{

    public $id;

    public $code;

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->code;
    }
}
```

The form works fine when I want to create an entity. But, in edit, I lost the initial selection and I got "Please select motif...".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you post your edit controller?

Comment: it's a symfony issue https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8825

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally foud the cause of the problem. it's a Symfony Framwork issue : [[Form] ObjectChoiceList should select initial field value based on the value property.](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8825)

I Had to write a class that I named `ValueBasedObjectChoiceList` in order to overcome the problem.

I hope this could help people having the same issue.